# Soup UI - save JSON request and response

Tags: json, rest, soapui

I'm using rest request in soapUI.
I want to save the JSON request and response to a file.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Request payload (JSON) is not included in the report.  Only request HTTP headers are captured in the report.  Please let me know if you are able to log request JSON. I am using SoapUI 5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your testSuite and select **Launch TestRunner**, on Launch TestRunner panel select **Reports tab**, on this tab check **Exports all results**, and select a root folder to save this results on **Root Folder:**. Finally click on **Launch**.

Then in your root folder for each request you will have a file like TestSuiteName-TestCaseName-TestStepName-nIteration-result.txt with following content:

```
Status: OK
Time Taken: 409
Size: 793
Timestamp: Mon Apr 07 12:47:02 CEST 2014
TestStep: Test Request

----------------- Messages ------------------------------

----------------- Properties ------------------------------
Encoding: UTF-8
Endpoint: http://myHost.com/service/service

---------------- Request ---------------------------
Request Headers: Host : XX.XXX.X.XX
Content-Length : 321
SOAPAction : "http://myAction.com"
Accept-Encoding : gzip,deflate
User-Agent : Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
Connection : Keep-Alive
Content-Type : text/xml;charset=UTF-8

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <element/>
      <element/>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
...
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

---------------- Response --------------------------
Response Headers: Date : Mon, 07 Apr 2014 10:48:34 GMT
#status# : HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Length : 793
Expires : Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type : text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Connection : close
Server : XXXXXXXXXXXX
Cache-Control : no-cache
Pragma : no-cache


<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
...
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

If you prefer to save only request and response with no additional information you can take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908419/unable-to-save-testsuite-response-result-in-soap-ui/22909711#22909711) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010177/downloading-soap-response-as-xml-file/22069096#22069096).

Hope this helps,