# Unable to save TestSuite Response Result in SOAP UI

Tags: soapui

Can we save all SOAP responses from test step inside TestSuite with SOAPUI?

I try to save all responses through DATA export , but its only showing me summary result like how many  test case pass/fail. But I want to save response result for all request of the TestSuite.

Answer (score 2):

To save all response from a `testSuite` you can add a `tearDown script` which is executed at the end of `testSuite` execution. This groovy script loops over each `testCase` in the `testSuite` saving to disk each testStep response:

```java
// path for the testSuite
def folderPath =  'C:/temp/' + testSuite.name + '_' + System.currentTimeMillis() + File.separator
new File(folderPath).mkdirs()

// for each testCase in the testSuite
testSuite.testCases.each { testCaseName, testCase ->

    // path for this testCase
    def folderPathSuite = folderPath + testCaseName + File.separator
    new File(folderPathSuite).mkdir()

    // for each testStep
    testCase.testSteps.each { testStepName, testStep ->

        // to avoid problems with testSteps which not has response value (such as groovy script)
        def response = testStep.getProperty('Response')?.getValue()
        if(response){
            // define a file 
            def file = new File(folderPathSuite + testStepName + '_response.xml')
            // get the response and write to file
            file.write(response)
        }
    }
}
```

The `tearDown script` tab in `testSuite` panel: `

[image]

#### All response in one file

If instead, as you commnet you want all responses in one file you can do the same in `tearDown script` but using this code:

```java
// create file to write all responses
def allResponses =  new File('C:/temp/' + testSuite.name + '_' + "AllResponses.xml")
def ls = System.getProperty("line.separator")
// for each testCase
testSuite.testCases.each { testCaseName, testCase ->

    allResponses << "TESTCASE: ${testCaseName}${ls}"

    // for each testStep
    testCase.testSteps.each { testStepName, testStep ->

        allResponses << "TESTSTEP: ${testStepName}${ls}"
        // to avoid problems with testSteps which not has response value (such as groovy script)
        def response = testStep.getProperty('Response')?.getValue()
        if(response){
        // save the response to file
            allResponses << response + ls
        }
        allResponses << "END TESTSTEP: ${testStepName}${ls}"
    }

    allResponses << "END TESTCASE: ${testCaseName}${ls}"
}
```

If as you comment you want all this data in a `.xls` column, you need some external libraries to work with `.xls`as for example [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). IMO that is too much tricky to do so in your test.

If you want to do it anyway, take the Apache POI jars and copy it on `SOAPUI/bin/ext` folder, then restart SOAPUI in order to load the libraries. Now `groovy script` on your SOAPUI are ready to work with `.xls` using Apache POI classes. Here is a little example to start with [groovy and Apache POI](http://www.technipelago.se/blog/show/groovy-poi-excel).

Comment: Thanks for giving solution for my query. It is working. But I required some customized result. Like here its showing me in different files for each test cases , Is there any way all test cases  response added in one file only( in specific Column in xls) .

Comment: do you still look this? if yes, please let me know

Comment: @ChanGan Is this comment for me? or for the OP?