# SOAP UI Reporting

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am using open Source version of SOAPUI.
My requirement is to export SOAP Response XML into a file (e.f txt). I could not find any such option in  open source for this purpose. Please suggest if there is any way to do it or Groovy scripting is the solution. If yes then how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save a simple SOAP Test step response, you can add a groovy script with this code to do so:

```
// get your response
def soapResponse = context.expand('${YourSOAPRequest#Response}')
// create the file
def file = new File("C:/Temp/testSO/response.xml")
file.mkdirs()
// save the response
file.write(soapResponse)
```

Note that `YourSOAPRequest` is the name of your SOAP Test step.

Additionally if you want to save all the test step responses of the Test suite or the Test case this answer could help you: [Unable to save TestSuite Response Result in SOAP UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908419/unable-to-save-testsuite-response-result-in-soap-ui)

Comment: @albciff..u r answer worked for me. But what if I want to pass a variable for my SOAPRequest in line :def soapResponse = context.expand('${YourSOAPRequest#Response}')   Tried much but couldn't figure out

Comment: @NipunKumar sorry I don't understand your question, can you explain me your question with more detail?

Comment: @albciff..I am passing test Step name(ie Soap request name) in variable and execute the testStep . Now I want to capture the response using this variable (not static TestStep name) e.g if def A= "SoapRequest1" then I want to use A in following code line rather than 'SoapRequest1'....def soapResponse = context.expand('${SoapRequest1#Response}')

Comment: @NipunKumar if you have your test step name in string variable, you can simply concatenate this string using `+` operator to make the "expand" string, take a look at the follow code: `def A = "SOAPRequest1"; def soapResponse = context.expand('${' + A + '#Response}');`

Comment: @albciff...thanks for quick answer. I was concatenating with double quotes. I also figured out another working way :)

Answer (score 0):

You could run your tests from the [command line](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/functional-tests.html), with the `-a` or `-A` switch.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @albciff for guiding me through the answer. I also figured out a way for situtaion when rather than a static SOAP request name we have a variable:

def soapResponse= testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName(testStepName).getProperty("Response").getValue()

Now this response can be used to save