# SoapUI write testsuite name to file

Tags: groovy, soapui

I want to print my test suite into file

```
def fileDir = new File("C:\\SoapUIResults");
if(!fileDir .exists()) {
    fileDir .mkdirs();
} def myFile= new File(fileDir , "myFile.txt");  //If the file does not already exist, we want to create it, otherwise we want to append 
if(!myFile.exists()) {    myFile.createNewFile(); }

myFile.append(testRunner.testSuite.name +'\n' );    //Test suite Name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is not clear for me, the only thing that I see wrong in your code is that you are missing testCase to access testSuite properties from testRunner, to do so you must use `testRunner.testCase.testSuite.name` instead of `testRunner.testSuite.name`.

If you are looking for a way to save all testSuite results on a file take a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904478/soup-ui-save-json-request-and-response/22910449#22910449)

Hope this helps,